# Continuity of Markov chain' trasnition matrix functions

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, derivatives, continuity, markov-chains

I'm studying **Continuous-time Markov chains**.

Given the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Continuous-time_Markov_chain) of **continous-time transition functions matrix**:

$P(t) = (P\small{ij}(t)) = \mathbb{P}(X\small{t} = j | X\small{0} = i)$

So I have two questions related to continuity of this functions:

1. Can there be transitional functions which are non-continous?
2. Can there be transitional functions which are continuous, but non-differentiable?

Comment: idk what definition in wikipedia ur referring to. can u write it down in your post? also, id bet the answers to ur 2 questions are both "yes"

Comment: It's already written here.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. For the matrix $P(t)$ to generate a Markov process, $\{P(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ must be what is called a *semigroup*. This property is powerful as it essentially relates the Markov matrix at different times in a very particular way that enforces a lot of regularity. It is true that any semigroup associated with a Markov process is what is called *strongly continuous*, which translates to each component of $P(t)$ being continuous if $P(t)$ is a matrix.
2. I believe the answer to this is also no, at least if the Markov process is time-homogeneous. It is also true that Markov semigroups are what are called *contraction semigroups*, which implies that they have a densly defined *infinitesimal generator*, which is basically $P'(0)$. Because of the semigroup property, $P'(0) = P'(t)$ for any $t\geq 0$. If this operator is densly defined, then this implies that each component is differentiable. I'm not sure about the non-time homogeneous case.

This stuff is usually discussed in much more general infinite-dimensional frameworks but I believe these results translate to the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Isn't the question already assuming that we are working with the definitions given in the linked Wikipedia article, implying in particular that we are working with a homogeneous Markov chain??

Comment: Sure but I just wanted to be up front about in what situations I thought these answers may be false

Comment: Okay, but then perhaps I would either briefly describe this in a comment, or else (if too long for a comment) begin the answer by saying that this is not actually an answer to the question asked, but rather addressing first the perhaps more fundamental question of what happens when the question's hypotheses are relaxed. As currently written, it looks like what you've written is the actual final answer to the OP's original question.

Comment: @whpowell96 Why is any Markov semigroup is strongly continous? And why is it a contraction semigroup?

Comment: I actually left something out. For a Markov sermigroup to be strongly continuous, it must be a Feller process, which means that the space of continuous and bounded functions are invariant under the Markov semigroup. Feller property implies strong continuity as well as the contraction property. Also needed for the contraction property is the fact that the Markov semigroup can be viewed as a set of evolving probability measures, each of which integrates to $1$, hence the contraction.

Comment: @whpowell96 So does it mean that there is an example of non-continuous/non-differential matrices in general?

Comment: I still think that in the case of matrices, i.e., discrete state space, it still may be true that everything is continuous and differentiable since the functions spaces over a discrete space are so much simpler than those over a continuum, but I could be wrong